# How to achieve this view?

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve this view:
[image]

I can do it with tables but when I do it with DIVs it just collapses. I did like this:

```
    <div class="fl25"><h3>S&ouml;kande och uppfinnare</h3></div>
        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="fl20">Registrera:</div>
        <div class="fl15"><input type="checkbox"    name="<%= PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_ADD_SOKANDE %>">S&ouml;kande</div>
        <div class="fl15"><input type="checkbox"    <% if (ansokanInfo.getUppfinnareList().contains(editPerson)) { %> 
    checked="checked""
    <% } %> name="<%= PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_ADD_UPPFINNARE %>">Uppfinnare</div>

        <div class="clear lh10"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
<div class="example1">
    <div class="example_column1"><fieldset class="whiteborder">
         <legend><i>Fysisk person</i></legend><br> 
        <div class="fl20">F&ouml;rnamn:</div>
        <div class="fl20"><input type="text" size="20" value="<%=editPerson.getFornamn() %>" name="<%= PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_FORNAMN %>"></div>       
        <div class="fl20">Efternamn:</div>
        <div class="fl20"><input type="text" size="20" value="<%=editPerson.getEfternamn() %>" name="<%= PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_EFTERNAMN %>"></div>
        </fieldset></div>
    <div class="example_column2">
        <div class="fl20">S&ouml;k person/f&ouml;retag<input type="button" value="S&ouml;k" onClick="getElementById('popupSokNamn').style.display=''">
        </div>
    </div>
```

With CSS

```
.whiteborder {     color: #ffffff;      border: 3px solid #ffffff;      padding: 10px;      margin: 10px; }

div.example1
{
width: 500;
color: #ffffff;
}
div.example1 div
{
float: left;
height: 100px;
}
div.example1 div.example_column1
{
width: 450px;
}
div.example1 div.example_column2
{
width: 50px;
}
```

Now that is not working although it appears to be the right thing to do. Now I'm lost for ideas which the one way is of achieving the view which is so easy to do with tables and nearly impossible to do with `DIV`s

Can you advice me how to do the view? i asked about this before but the scope was insufficient ([How to make a white square around my form fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633443/how-to-make-a-white-square-around-my-form-fields))

I've made my best effort and I can't seem to place the button with "Sök person/företag" to the right and the labels for the form don't align properly either:

[image]

The code I used is

```
        <div class="fl25"><h3>S&ouml;kande och uppfinnare</h3></div>
        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="fl20">Registrera:</div>
        <div class="fl15"><input type="checkbox"    name="<%= PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_ADD_SOKANDE %>">S&ouml;kande</div>
        <div class="fl15"><input type="checkbox"    <% if (ansokanInfo.getUppfinnareList().contains(editPerson)) { %> 
    checked="checked""
    <% } %> name="<%= PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_ADD_UPPFINNARE %>">Uppfinnare</div>

<div class="fl20"><input type="button" value="S&ouml;k person/f&ouml;retag"></div>
        <div class="clear lh10"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="fl20"></div>&nbsp;
                <fieldset class="whiteborder"><legend><i>Fysisk person</i></legend> 
    <br>        
        <div class="fl20">F&ouml;rnamn::</div>
        <div class="fl20"><input type="text" size="60" value="<%=editPerson.getFornamn() %>" name="<%= PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_FORNAMN %>"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="fl20">Efternamn:</div>
        <div class="fl20"><input type="text" size="60" value="<%=editPerson.getEfternamn() %>" name="<%= PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_EFTERNAMN %>"></div>
        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
        </fieldset>
```

### Update

The answers did not work for me. I can achieve nearly what I want but it's not complete:
[image]
All the code to render the page is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <link href="css_js/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css_js/positions.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css_js/floats.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="css_js/sorttable.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript1.2" src="css_js/general_arendeprocess.js"></script>

    <script language="JavaScript1.2" type="text/javascript">
    function ingVar(x) { 
    var applicationDependence;
    applicationDependence = x;
    document.getElementById('ff').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('avd').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('utb').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('oepa').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('aooep').style.display='none';
    if (applicationDependence == 'ff'){ 
            document.getElementById('ob').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('ff').style.display='';
            }
    if  (applicationDependence == 'avd'){
            document.getElementById('ob').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('avd').style.display='';
            }
    if  (applicationDependence == 'utb'){
            document.getElementById('ob').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('utb').style.display='';
            }       
    if  (applicationDependence == 'oepa'){
            document.getElementById('ob').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('oepa').style.display='';
            }
    if  (applicationDependence == 'aooep'){
            document.getElementById('ob').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('aooep').style.display='';
            }       
    if  (applicationDependence == 'ob'){
            document.getElementById('ob').style.display='';
            }       
    }
    </script>
    <title>Ingivningsdag - NAT. - Pandora </title>
</head>






<body><form name="actionForm" action="PandoraActionServlet" style="display: inline;" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="currPage" value="/PandoraArendeWeb/20120306_grunduppgifter.jsp" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="actionCommand" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="actionModifier" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="actionTarget" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="destination" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currIndex" value="" />
    <div id="top">
        <div id="av_logga">
            <br>
            <span class="small60">Nummer: <input type="text" size="40"> <input type="button" value="S&ouml;k"></span>
        </div>
        <img src="../images/prvision.gif" alt="" width="109" height="30" border="0" style="margin: 4px 13px;">
        <div class="avnamn">
            Pandora
        </div>
        <div  id="flikkant" class="flikkant1">
            <span class="sub_meny_r"><img src="../images/avdelare.gif" alt="" width="2" height="20" border="0" style="display: inline;"></span>
            <span class="sub_meny_r sub_meny_rm">Logga ut</span>
            <span class="sub_meny_r"><img src="../images/avdelare.gif" alt="" width="2" height="20" border="0" style="display: inline;"></span>
            <span class="sub_meny_r sub_meny_rm">?</span>
            <span class="sub_meny_r"><img src="../images/avdelare.gif" alt="" width="2" height="20" border="0" style="display: inline;"></span>
            <span class="sub_meny_r sub_meny_rm">S&ouml;k</span>
            <span class="sub_meny_r"><img src="../images/avdelare.gif" alt="" width="2" height="20" border="0" style="display: inline;"></span> 
            <img src="../images/avdelare.gif" alt="" width="2" height="20" border="0" style="display: inline;">
            <a href="ankomstregistrering.html"><span class="sub_meny">Ankomst</span></a>
            <img src="../images/avdelare.gif" alt="" width="2" height="20" border="0" style="display: inline;">
            <a href="formalialista.html"><span class="sub_meny_active">Formell</span></a>
            <img src="../images/avdelare.gif" alt="" width="2" height="20" border="0" style="display: inline;">
            <a href="formalialista.html"><span class="sub_meny">Juridisk</span></a>
            <img src="../images/avdelare.gif" alt="" width="2" height="20" border="0" style="display: inline;">
            <span class="sub_meny">Teknisk</span>
            <img src="../images/avdelare.gif" alt="" width="2" height="20" border="0" style="display: inline;">
            <span class="sub_meny">Publicering</span>
            <img src="../images/avdelare.gif" alt="" width="2" height="20" border="0" style="display: inline;">
            <span class="sub_meny"> Kundregister</span>
            <img src="../images/avdelare.gif" alt="" width="2" height="20" border="0" style="display: inline;">
            <span class="sub_meny">Expediering</span>
            <img src="../images/avdelare.gif" alt="" width="2" height="20" border="0" style="display: inline;">
        </div><!-- filkkant -->
</div><!-- top -->


<!-- F-handl&auml;ggning -->
<div id="sub" class="sub">
    <span style="float:right">
         <span class="sub_meny_sm">Senast &ouml;ppnade:</span> 
         <span class="sub_meny_sm link">1234567-9</span>
          <span class="sub_meny_sm link">1234567-9</span>
         <span class="sub_meny_sm link">S&ouml;kresultat</span>
    </span>
    <a href=formellkontroll.html><span class="sub_meny_active " onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline'" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none'" >Formell kontroll</span> </a>
     <a href=fordelalista.html><span class="sub_meny " onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline'" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none'">F&ouml;rdelning</span> </a>
    <a href=klassningslista.html><span class="sub_meny " onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline'" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none'">Klassning</span> </a>
</div><!-- sub -->

<div id="yta">
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" align="center" class="TB_bo" style="border-bottom:0;">
<tr>
    <td class="TD_bo hknot"> <a href=oversikt.html><span onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline'" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none'">&Ouml;versikt</span></a></td>
        <td class="TD_bo hk TB_bo_hk sub_meny_active">Grunduppgifter</td>
    <td class="TD_bo hknot"> <a href=checklista.html><span  onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline'" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none'">Checklista</span> </a></td>
    <td class="TD_bo hknot"> <a href=klass.html><span  onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline'" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none'">Klass</span> </a></td>
    <td class="TD_bo hknot"> <a href=its.html><span onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline'" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none'">ITS</span> </a></td>
    <td class="TD_bo hknot"> <a href=frister><span  onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline'" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none'">Status</span> </a></td>
    <td class="TD_bo hknot"> <a href=handlingar><span  onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline'" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none'">Handlingar</span> </a></td>
    <td class="TD_bo hknot"> <a href=frister><span  onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline'" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none'">Frister</span> </a></td>
    <td class="TD_bo2 hknot"> <a href=rapporter><span  onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline'" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none'">Rapporter</span> </a></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" align="center" class="TB_bo2B">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1" class="pusher td40"><h1>Svensk patentans&ouml;kan</h1></td>
        <td rowspan="2" width="40%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="3"><span class="link">Visa akt</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="pusher"><h1>SE 9304251-3</h1><h2 class="pusher">Inte offentlig</h2></td>
        <td class="link ssmall">Betalningar</td>
        <td class="link ssmall">Dagbok</td>
        <td class="link ssmall">Noteringar</td>
    </tr>
</table>



<!--sidinneh&aring;ll-->

<div class="yta2  TB_nb fontS80 ">
    <div class="clear ">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="fr1 ">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="fr5 "><input type="button" value="Historik"></div>
    <div class="fl30"><h2>Grunduppgifter</h2></div>
    <div class="clear quarter">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="clear "></div>

<div id="indag" class="yta2   TB_nb fontS80">
    <div class="clear half">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="fl10"><h3>Ingivningsdag</h3></div>

    <div class="fl20">Ans&ouml;kans beroende:</div>
    <div class="fl20"><select name="ansokanBeroende" onchange="ingVar(this.value);">
    <option value="ob" SELECTED>Oberoende ans&ouml;kan</option>
    <option value="ff">Fullf&ouml;ljd</option>
    <option value="avd">Avdelad</option>
    <option value="utb">Utbruten</option>
    <option value="oepa">Omvandlad EP-ans&ouml;kan</option>
    <option value="aooep">Avdelad och omvandlad EP-ans&ouml;kan</option>
    </select></div>
    <div class="fl10">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="fl1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="fl20"><input type="checkbox" value="">Ingivningsdag kan inte tilldelas</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div id="ob">
        <div class="fr10 smallg">F&ouml;rnamn Efternamn,<br>handl&auml;ggarkod<br><br></div>
        <div class="fl10"></div>
        <div id="datum" class="fl20">Datum ingivningsdag:</div>
        <div class="fl20"><input type="text" name="ingivningsdag" 
    id="ingivningsdag" value="">&nbsp;<img src="images/cal.gif" alt="" width="16" height="15" border="0" onclick="javascript:openCalWin('620','300','ingivningsdag')"></div>

    </div>

    <div id="ff" style="display: none;">
        <div class="fr10 smallg">F&ouml;rnamn Efternamn,<br>handl&auml;ggarkod</div>
        <div class="fl10"></div>
        <div class="fl20">Fullf&ouml;ljd fr&aring;n:</div>
        <div class="fl20"><input type="text"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="fl10"></div>
        <div class="fl20">WO-nummer:</div>
        <div class="fl20"><input type="text"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="fl10"></div>
        <div class="fl20">Internationell ingivningsdag:</div>
        <div class="fl20"><input type="text">&nbsp;<img src="../images/minikal.jpg" alt="" width="16" height="15" border="0"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="avd" style="display: none;">
        <div class="fr10 smallg">F&ouml;rnamn Efternamn,<br>handl&auml;ggarkod</div>
        <div class="fl10"></div>
        <div class="fl20">Avdelad fr&aring;n:</div>
        <div class="fl20"><input type="text"><input type="button" value="S&ouml;k"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="fl10"></div>
        <div id="datum" class="fl20">Datum ingivningsdag:</div>
        <div class="fl20"><input type="text">&nbsp;<img src="../images/minikal.jpg" alt="" width="16" height="15" border="0"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="utb" style="display: none;">
        <div class="fr10 smallg">F&ouml;rnamn Efternamn,<br>handl&auml;ggarkod</div>
        <div class="fl10"></div>
        <div class="fl20">Utbruten fr&aring;n:</div>
        <div class="fl20"><input type="text"><input type="button" value="S&ouml;k"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="fl10"></div>
        <div id="datum" class="fl20">Datum ingivningsdag:</div>
        <div class="fl20"><input type="text">&nbsp;<img src="../images/minikal.jpg" alt="" width="16" height="15" border="0"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="oepa" style="display: none;">
        <div class="fr10 smallg">F&ouml;rnamn Efternamn,<br>handl&auml;ggarkod</div>
        <div class="fl10"></div>
        <div class="fl20">EP- ans&ouml;kningsnummer:</div>
        <div class="fl20"><input type="text"><input type="button" value="S&ouml;k"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="fl10"></div>
        <div id="datum" class="fl20">Ankomstdatum (EP-ans&ouml;kan)<br>eller ingivningsdag  (EP-ans&ouml;kan):</div>
        <div class="fl20 mt5p"><input type="text">&nbsp;<img src="../images/minikal.jpg" alt="" width="16" height="15" border="0"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="aooep" style="display: none;">
        <div class="fr10 smallg">F&ouml;rnamn Efternamn,<br>handl&auml;ggarkod</div>
        <div class="fl10"></div>
        <div class="fl20">Avdelad fr&aring;n:</div>
        <div class="fl20"><input type="text"><input type="button" value="S&ouml;k"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="fl10"></div>
        <div class="fl20">EP- ans&ouml;kningsnummer:</div>
        <div class="fl20"><input type="text"><input type="button" value="S&ouml;k"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="fl10"></div>
        <div id="datum" class="fl20">Ankomstdatum (EP-ans&ouml;kan)<br>eller ingivningsdag  (EP-ans&ouml;kan):</div>
        <div class="fl20 mt5p"><input type="text">&nbsp;<img src="../images/minikal.jpg" alt="" width="16" height="15" border="0"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="fl10"></div>


    <div class="clear"></div>
</div><!-- indag -->

<div class="clear lh10">&nbsp;</div>

<div id="sokupp" class="yta2   TB_nb fontS80">
    <div class="fl50" id="L-col">
        <div class="clear half">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="fl25"><h3>S&ouml;kande och uppfinnare</h3></div>
        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="fl20">Registrera:</div>
        <div class="fl15"><input type="checkbox"    name="addSokande">S&ouml;kande</div>
        <div class="fl15"><input type="checkbox"     
    checked="checked""
     name="addUppfinnare">Uppfinnare</div>

<div class="fl20"><input type="button" value="S&ouml;k person/f&ouml;retag"></div>
        <div class="clear lh10"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="fl20"></div>&nbsp;
                <fieldset class="whiteborder"><legend><i>Fysisk person</i></legend> 
    <br>        
        <div class="fl20">F&ouml;rnamn:</div>
        <div class="fl20"><input type="text" size="60" value="Lo 3" name="fornamn"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="fl20">Efternamn:</div>
        <div class="fl20"><input type="text" size="60" value="Tass 3" name="efternamn"></div>
        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
        </fieldset>
    &nbsp;
        <fieldset class="whiteborder"><legend><i>Juridisk person</i></legend> 

    <br>

        <div class="fl20">F&ouml;retag:</div>
        <div class="fl20"><input type="text" size="60" value="" name="foretag"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="fl20">Organisationsnummer:</div>
        <div class="fl20"><input type="text" size="60" name="orgnummer"></div>
        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="fl20">Attention, c/o etc:</div>
        <div class="fl40"><input type="text" size="60" name="att" value=""></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="fl20">Postadress:</div>
        <div class="fl40"><input type="text" size="60" name="postadress" value=""></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="fl20">Postnummer:</div>
        <div class="fl40"><input type="text" size="30" name="postnr" value=""></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="fl20">Postort:</div>
        <div class="fl40"><input type="text" size="30" name="postort" value=""></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="fl20">Land:</div>
        <div class="fl40"><input type="text" size="2" value="SE" name="landkod">&nbsp;
                    <select name="">
                        <option value="1" SELECTED></option>
                        <option value="2"></option>
                        <option value="3"></option>
                        <option value="4"></option>
                        <option value="5">---------------------------------</option>
        </select></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="fl20">Region:</div>
        <div class="fl20"><select name="region">
                        <option value="1" SELECTED></option>
                        <option value="2"></option>
                        <option value="3"></option>
                        <option value="4"></option>
                        <option value="5">-----------------------------------------------</option>
        </select></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="fl20">Tel:</div>
        <div class="fl40"><input type="text" size="40" name="tel"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="fl20">Fax:</div>
        <div class="fl40"><input type="text" size="40" name="fax"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="fl20">E-post:</div>
        <div class="fl40"><input type="text" size="60" name="epost"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="fl20">&nbsp;</div>

        <div class="clear lh10 bb fl80">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="clear half">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="fl20">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="fl20"><input type="button" value="Ta bort"></div>
        <div class="fl20"><input type="button" value="Avbryt">&nbsp;<input type="button" value="L&auml;gg till" onclick="javascript:doSubmitWithTarget('Grunduppgifter','addPerson','')"></div>
    </div>
```

...

### Update

I could get close but it's impossible to do the simple thing I want since the graphic components behave completely randomly going left, right or down for no appearant reason. The view I can achieve is:

[image]

The code that does this nearly the way I want is:

```
<div id="sokupp" class="yta2   TB_nb fontS80">
    <div class="fl50" id="L-col">
        <div class="clear half">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="fl25"><h3>S&ouml;kande och uppfinnare</h3></div>
        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="fl20">Registrera:</div>
        <div class="fl15"><input type="checkbox"    name="addSokande">S&ouml;kande</div>
        <div class="fl15"><input type="checkbox"     
    checked="checked""
     name="addUppfinnare">Uppfinnare</div>

<div class="fl20"><input type="button" value="S&ouml;k person/f&ouml;retag"></div>
        <div class="clear lh10"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="fl20"></div>

            <div id="example1">     <div class="example_column1"><fieldset class="whiteborder">     
                 <legend><i>Fysisk person</i></legend><br> <table><tr><td>    
                      <div>F&ouml;rnamn:</div>  </td><td>
                      <div><input type="text" size="20" value="Bla" name="blub"></div></td></tr>   
                      <tr><td><div>Efternamn:</div></td><td>
                      <div><input type="text" size="20" value="bli" name="blu"></div></td></tr></table> 
                      </fieldset>     </div>  
                      <div class="example_column2"><div class="fl20">S&ouml;k person/f&ouml;retag<input type="button" value="S&ouml;k" onClick="getElementById('popupSokNamn').style.display=''"></div>      </div> </div>
```

### Solution

In this case I could finally make it work using this code:

HTML

```
<div id="example1">
<div class="example_column1">
<fieldset class="whiteborder"> <legend><i>Fysisk person</i></legend>
F&ouml;rnamn:<input type="text" size="60" value="Bla" name="blub">
Efternamn:<input type="text" size="60" value="Bla" name="blub"></fieldset>
</div>
<br><br><div class="example_column2">
S&ouml;k person/<br>f&ouml;retag:<br>
<input type="button" value="S&ouml;k" onClick="getElementById('popupSokNamn').style.display=''">
</div> </div>
```

CSS

```
.whiteborder {     color: #ffffff;      border: 3px solid #ffffff;      padding: 10px;      margin: 10px; }
#example1 { width: 550; color: #ffffff; }
.example_column1 {     color: #000000; margin: 0;      padding: 0;     width: 470px;     border:0;     float: left; }
.example_column2 {     color: #000000;margin: 0;      padding: 0;     border:0;     width: 80px;     float: right; }
```

Comment: you can accomplish this very easily please provide you page code and css because i am not able to generate the entire scenario for me. Please provide fiddle/demo example so i can help you as ASAP.

Comment: Are you having problems getting the fields and labels inside the `<fieldset>` aligned? Then the answer is simple: **If you want to align things as if they were in a table, use a table**. That is one of the very typical examples where you *should* use a table instead of throwing around ´<div>`s.

Comment: @Nick Rosencrantz check my answer an let me know i am lagging some where.

Comment: If you provide me your whole code or demo i can solve your issues quickly.

Comment: @Happy Singh It's not working and neither is pasting all of my code since it's too much code. I could paste the entire thing to http://pastebin.com/5wi2Q3dW and I don't think it will work with DIVs since too many DIVs make the graphic component behave completely randomly, going left, right and down for no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
<html><head><style>
div {background: gray;}
.whiteborder {     color: #ffffff;      border: 3px solid #ffffff;      padding: 10px;      margin: 10px; }
#example1
{
width: 500;
color: #ffffff;
}
.example_column1
{
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    width: 450px;
    border:0;
    float: left;
}
.example_column2
{
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    border:0;
    width: 50px;
    float: right;
}

</style></head>
<body>

<div id="example1">
    <div class="example_column1"><fieldset class="whiteborder">
         <legend><i>Fysisk person</i></legend><br> 
        <div>F&ouml;rnamn:</div>
        <div><input type="text" size="20" value="Bla" name="blub"></div>       
        <div>Efternamn:</div>
        <div><input type="text" size="20" value="bli" name="blu"></div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
     <div class="example_column2">
        <div>S&ouml;k person/f&ouml;retag<input type="button" value="S&ouml;k" onClick="getElementById('popupSokNamn').style.display=''"></div>
     </div>
</div>
</body>
```

In my browser that looks quite similar to the result you want. A few points I think I should mention:

- For debugging purposes I like to give all elements a coloured border (`border: 1px solid red` for example). That can be a problem when working with fixed width layouts:
- When using fixed pixel width, setting `margin`, `padding` and `border` explicitly to 0 can help a lot. A border of 1 pixel is added to the width of the column, so example_column1 would be 450 + 2 = 452 pixel wide. That makes example_column2 too wide to fit in the overall example1 container of 500 pixels, and you will never get them to dislpay side by side.
- In general, when you run into this sort of problem, strip down your html to the basic minimum required to reproduce your problem, and then adjust your css. For example in this case I threw out all the fieldset stuff and used only three empty div's (example1, example_column1 and example_column2), until I got them aligned properly. Then I added the fieldset back in to see how the whole thing was displayed.

Comment: Thanks but it is not working since other elements on the page may be conflicting. The button displays underneath the fieldset and the fieldset displays too far to the right.

Comment: Then you may have the spacing issue I described above. Try to give example1 more space, e.g. 600 pixels, and leave the columns  at 450 and 50 pixels, see if that helps.

Comment: Of course it's not working since layout with divs behave completely randomly. Changing the space to 600 pixeln in a random way moved the fieldset to the left but the button is still below the fieldset instead of to the right since making a lyaout with div makes the component behave in a complete random way, going right, left and down for no appearant reason. DIVs for layout really suck since I can't expect to know what the result will be when the component behave completely randomly.

Comment: There is no randomness in a div layout, they are completely logical. (But I admit that sometimes we humans have problems understanding that logic...) The best advice I can give you is to read up on the css box model, to get a better understanding of what is going on, especially with styles like `position` and `float`. The specification at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html is a good *reference*, but did little to improve my *understandig*. Maybe http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/boxmodel is a good starting point for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and comments. It shouldn't take a week to make two columns. The way the graphic components align in all ways except the way we want is completely random to a programmer who is used to being able to control what is instructed by the code. This way we've effectively made it impossible to achieve something simple: All I want is another column and I must learn the entire model of CSS? That's not practical and doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Maybe it's my browser, but using exactly the code you pasted, .example_column1 and .example_column2 don't align to two columns, they become two column in two rows. The reason for this is of course that DIVs behave completely unreliable, unpredictable and impossible to work with. All I wanted was 2 columns and I shouldn't have to waste an entire week of work just because DIVs are useless for layouts.

Comment: @Nick: You're right. I needed to add `float: left;` to the style of `.example_column1`. But I suspect that the result isn't what you want, either... As stated in my comment to your question, if you want to align things in a **table**, it is quite ok to use a `<table>`. It seems that not using `<table>` is a requirement from your colleagues or your boss? Give them my regards, and tell them that I sincerely question the wisdom of that requirement. We certainly shouldn't use tables for *page layout* any more. But if you need to align some form fields, they are a (very) viable solution.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. With your instructions I could finally get it working having been doing this since monday and getting it to work first today. I'm updating the original question with the code that worked for me. Thanks again.